# New nagios install segfaults on startup

Tags: nagios

I'm having some nagios [trouble](https://serverfault.com/questions/772706/nagios-setup-stopped-working?s=8|0.0000) which I hoped to solve by a clean install, but no dice.

I retrieved https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/releases/nagios-4.1.1.tar.gz, and did as little as possible:

```
./configure --with-command-group=nagcmd
make all
make install
make install-init
make install-config
make install-commandmode
```

I haven't touched the config files at all; I'm just using the sample files.

```
root@MEDIO-SRV10:/# /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Nagios Core 4.1.1
Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 08-19-2015
License: GPL

Website: https://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
   Read main config file okay...
   Read object config files okay...

Running pre-flight check on configuration data...

Checking objects...
        Checked 8 services.
        Checked 1 hosts.
        Checked 1 host groups.
        Checked 0 service groups.
        Checked 1 contacts.
        Checked 1 contact groups.
        Checked 24 commands.
        Checked 5 time periods.
        Checked 0 host escalations.
        Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking for circular paths...
        Checked 1 hosts
        Checked 0 service dependencies
        Checked 0 host dependencies
        Checked 5 timeperiods
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...

Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   0

Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check
```

Nagios appears to start, but dies immediately.

```
root@MEDIO-SRV10:/# /etc/init.d/nagios start
Starting nagios: done.
root@MEDIO-SRV10:/# /etc/init.d/nagios status
nagios is not running
root@MEDIO-SRV10:/# tail /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22469;pid=22469
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22471;pid=22471
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22470;pid=22470
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22472;pid=22472
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22473;pid=22473
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22467;pid=22467
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22468;pid=22468
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22475;pid=22475
[1461851951] wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 22474;pid=22474
[1461851951] Caught SIGSEGV, shutting down...
```

Same when I'm running as a foreground process:

```
root@MEDIO-SRV10:/# /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios  /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Nagios Core 4.1.1
Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 08-19-2015
License: GPL

Website: https://www.nagios.org
Nagios 4.1.1 starting... (PID=23487)
Local time is Thu Apr 28 15:59:58 CEST 2016
nerd: Channel hostchecks registered successfully
nerd: Channel servicechecks registered successfully
nerd: Channel opathchecks registered successfully
nerd: Fully initialized and ready to rock!
wproc: Successfully registered manager as @wproc with query handler
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23490;pid=23490
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23488;pid=23488
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23493;pid=23493
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23491;pid=23491
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23489;pid=23489
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23495;pid=23495
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23494;pid=23494
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23498;pid=23498
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23496;pid=23496
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23500;pid=23500
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23501;pid=23501
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23499;pid=23499
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23502;pid=23502
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23492;pid=23492
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23503;pid=23503
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23497;pid=23497
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23505;pid=23505
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23507;pid=23507
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23509;pid=23509
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23506;pid=23506
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23504;pid=23504
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23508;pid=23508
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23510;pid=23510
wproc: Registry request: name=Core Worker 23511;pid=23511
Segmentation fault
```

This is on a server running ubuntu 10.10. I've looked at ldd output (no problems) and strace output (no idea), and I'm at a loss. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Self-answering: turns out this is linked to update checking ([Cf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18491/nagios3-crashes-with-sigsegv)), and can easily be mitigated with the check_for_update flag in nagios.cnf.